# How to load a video file(located in assets folder ) in NDK?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am executing ffmpeg by android ndk, I am able to run an sample, here [https://github.com/ccggaass/android-ffmpeg-sample].

I want to put the video in android assets folder, so how to pass this file to the ffmpeg api:

av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, ***"file:/sdcard/vid.3gp"***, NULL, 0, NULL);

Does anyone know how to pass the file to av lib?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
String path = "/sdcard/vid.3gp";
av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, "file:/sdcard/vid.3gp", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the asset wont be compressed when the APK is built. ( so we can access its file descriptor ) 
Make sure Ffmpeg is built with the pipe protocol support.
Grab the assets file descriptor from the AAsset_manager.
build the filename like so...

char fn[32];
sprintf(fn,"pipe://%d", your_assets_fd);

open it like so...
av_open_input_file( x, fn, ... );

Good Luck.

P.S. don't hard-code the /sdcard/ path.

Comment: @Mar  your_assets_fd from AAsset_manager? is it can from getAssets().openFd("video.mp4").getFileDescriptor() ?

Answer (score -1):

maybe this will work

`file:///android_asset/vid.3gp`